# Embed a YouTube playlist but play the last video first

Tags: youtube, embed

How can I embed a YouTube playlist (from a channel I don’t manage) into my own website, but select the **last** video in the playlist as the one to play first?

Comment: For *last video*, you mean the latest/recent video added in the playlist or the last video (oldest video) in the playlist?

Comment: Playlists are sorted by whoever created them. They can be sorted chronologically, alphabetically, or in any custom order the creator wants, and when you want to embed someone else's playlist, that's the order you get. The particular playlist which prompted me to write the answer below is sorted from oldest video first to newest video last. Instead, I want the newest video to play first, and then I don't really care about the play order after that. The code in my answer simply sets the play position to the last video in the playlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly not as easy as it ought to be. You'd think you could just add an index parameter to the URL, as you can with Vimeo. But no.

You have to use the [PlaylistItems endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) of the YouTube Data API (yes, by creating a project in [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com) and generating an API key) to return a list of all the videos in the playlist, grab the video ID of the last item in the list, then build a URL for your `iframe` which includes both the video ID and the playlist ID.

```
const apiKey = [YOUR_API_KEY]
const playlistId = 'PL....'
const urlBase = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=' + playlistId + '&key=' + apiKey

const setIFrameSrc = async () => {
  let data = await fetch(urlBase).then(response => response.json())  // get first page of items
  while (data.nextPageToken)  // are there more items?
    data = await fetch(urlBase + '&pageToken=' + data.nextPageToken).then(response => response.json())  // get next page of items
  const snippet = data.items.pop().snippet  // pop() grabs the last item
  document.getElementById('[YOUR_IFRAME_ID]').src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + snippet.resourceId.videoId + '?listType=playlist&list=' + playlistId
}
setIFrameSrc()
```